# powershell - check if a variable contains all strings in an array

Tags: powershell

In powershell, how do I check if a variable contains all strings in an array?

for e.g.

`$variable = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog"
 $array = "quick brown","lazy dog"`

if variable contains all strings in array, return true.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that

```
"The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog".Contains("quick brown")
```

returns `True`.

You can try :

```
$variable = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog"
$array = "quick brown","lazy dog"
$result=$true
$array | ForEach-Object {$variable.Contains($_)} | ForEach-Object {$result= $result -and $_}
$result
```

I just test each string and `AND` the result, It shoud exists a better answer.